# nutch 2.2 generator java Runtime Exception during curl job failed

Tags: java, solr, nutch, runtimeexception, solrcloud

I am getting the below error during curl , sometimes it’s getting fail   .
I have number of collection ( en,es,it,..etc ) when i check daily several collection have been fail ( not pattern )  , it may be "en" collection today but , tomorrow it “en” will curl successfully,
Cannot identify any  partner or issue , have check inodes and disk space , no problem with those ,

Nutch                    : 2.2.1
Java                       : 1.7
Hbase                   : 0.90.4

yesterday for en

```
InjectorJob: java.lang.RuntimeException: job failed: name=[crawl_en_03_live]inject /software/bea/nutch/live/en_03/seed_03.txt, jobid=job_local406356849_0001
    at org.apache.nutch.util.NutchJob.waitForCompletion(NutchJob.java:54)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.run(InjectorJob.java:233)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.inject(InjectorJob.java:251)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.run(InjectorJob.java:273)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.main(InjectorJob.java:282)
```

another day for norther language

```
InjectorJob: Injecting urlDir: /software/bea/nutch/live/pt/seed.txt
InjectorJob: Using class org.apache.gora.hbase.store.HBaseStore as the Gora           storage class.
  InjectorJob: java.lang.RuntimeException: job failed: name=     [crawl_pt_live]inject /software/bea/nutch/live/pt/seed.txt,     jobid=job_local1327090171_0001
    at org.apache.nutch.util.NutchJob.waitForCompletion(NutchJob.java:54)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.run(InjectorJob.java:233)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.inject(InjectorJob.java:251)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.run(InjectorJob.java:273)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.main(InjectorJob.java:282)
```

any help appreciate

Comment: please help me resolve the issue